# problema con do while

Tags: php

toi haciendo una tabla de multiplicar ya la tengo en for y en while pero no me sale el do while no conosco mucho esa instruccion no se cual sea mi error

esta es con while

```
<?php
$t=8;
$i=8;

while($t<=10){

    echo "<h3> Tabla del $t </h3>";
    while($i<=12){
        echo "$t x $i = ".($t*$i) . "<br/>";
        $i++;
    }

    $i=8;
    $t++;    
}


?>
```

hice con do while pero no hace nada el programa

```
<?php
$t=8;
$i=8;

do{
   echo "<h3> Tabla del $t </h3>";

      echo "$t x $i = ".($t*$i) . "<br/>";
      $i++;

 $i=8;
 $t++; 
}   while($t<=10);
    while($i<=12);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas 2 loops `do while` al igual que tienes 2 `while` en el primer ejemplo. Tienes un poco de lio con los corchetes, quedaría así:

```
<?php

 $t=8;
 $i=8;

  do{
    echo "<h3> Tabla del $t </h3>";
    $i=8;

    do{     
       echo "$t x $i = ".($t*$i) . "<br/>";
       $i++;
    } while($i<=12);

  $t++;
  }while($t<=12);

?>
```